# Added a shadow to a UIImageView on a UITableView kills performance... why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITableView` that has three `UIImageView` views per cell, with three cell displaying on the view at one time (for a total of nine `UIImageView` views). Think of it as a bookshelf. Sometimes I can have as many as 500 books.

I've added shadow to the `UIImageView` with code that is this:

```
UIImageView *itemImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 7, 65, 75)];
itemImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
itemImageView.tag = 6;
itemImageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
itemImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, -1);
itemImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
itemImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
itemImageView.clipsToBounds = NO;
[cell.contentView addSubview:itemImageView];
```

When I add the shadow code, as seen above, scrolling performance is just totally killed and becomes choppy. Each image has a different `Rect` so the shadow has to be created for each item as it scrolls. Anyone have any tips on how to add shadows to my images on a `UITableView` without having this issue?

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10133182/242769

Answer (score 10):

You may see a performance improvement if you add

```
itemImageView.layer.shadowPath =
       [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:itemImageView.layer.bounds].CGPath;
```

But in general, layer operations like this will kill performance in a table view. I experienced exactly the same issue, and we just eliminated the shadow effect. It wasn't worth it.

Answer (score 4):

You should review the WWDC videos on CoreAnimation best practices. You can request that the rasterized copy of the shadow be cached in memory. Cocoa is definitely fast enough to render these shadows on the fly without falling back to a pre-rendered image.

Example:

```
itemImageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Also I up-voted the answer regarding UIBezierPath. This is also mentioned in the best practices, but setting the shadow path of a CALayer is a huge performance boost. You can also create some interesting special effects by manipulating the shadow path.

Comment: Adding shouldRasterize = YES absolutely killed the image quality. Any ideas why?

Comment: It is re-using one rasterized image for all layers in the hierarchy. Did you also set the shadow path to improve the image quality?

Comment: If the quality of the layer is degraded it's likely b/c you need to add the code: self.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]

Answer (score 1):

Shadows are expensive and will kill your performance.

A better approach is to render the shadowed image in the background, cache/save it and display it on the view when its ready.

Edit: You way wish to look at Core Graphics / CGImage routines. Specifically CGContextSetShadowWithColor will draw you a shadow.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html

Comment: You say your view looks like a bookshelf -- to me at least, that implies that everything with a shadow is rectangular (and probably the same size). Reusing the same shadow image definitely sounds like the way to go in that case. (And if your rectangles aren't all the same size, you can still reuse the image with UIImage's resizable image support.)

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be rectangular. It's possible to render a shadow image onto an arbitrary foreground then render that ontop of an arbitrary background. What I suggest is caching the image sandwich (foreground, shadow, background)

Comment: Thanks rickster... all of my images are rectangular. I will give this a shot and just resize it as needed and see how it looks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with adding shadow to labels inside a tableviewcell. I tried to layout the elements inside cellForRowAtIndexPath when the cell will be created:

```
if(cell == nil){
    //layout cell
```

These optimized the scrolling a little bit, but its quite choppy.

For optimizing your pictures quality you should add also the rasterizationScale if you activated "shouldRasterize":

```
aLabel.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
aLabel.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Maybe somebody has some ideas how to optimize the code to get the normal iOS scrolling. thx

Answer (score 0):

Do you activate reusing? If not, the cells will redone each time the view changes (e.g., during scrolling). That would eat a lot of performance for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my same question here: [App running slowly because of UIImageViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756235/app-running-slowly-because-of-uiimageviews)

I would use this code:

```
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath imageView.bounds];
imageView.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
```