# Smoothing Segues with Rasterization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calayer

I have a view controller that contains a button with six CAShapeLayer sublayers.  I've added `self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;` in the viewWillAppear: to improve a slight stuttering when the view controller is being segued to.  (I then turn off shouldRasterize in the view controller's viewDidAppear:).

The stuttering is almost completely gone, save for a very slight initial stutter just as the segue begins.  My guess is that this is caused by the rasterization itself.  This is the first time I've used shouldRasterize and I'm very pleased with the result, but I wanted to check if anyone else has experience improving segue performance this way and if this initial (very minor) stutter has been avoided.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133109/fastest-way-to-do-shadows-on-ios.

Comment: You should also set `rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale` or else it will look terrible on Retina screens.