# Adding shadows to views makes the UI lag

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to add shadows to views, each in a table view's content view, but as soon as I do the UI becomes incredibly unresponsive and laggy.

Does anyone know a better way to draw shadows than this:

```
mainView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
mainView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.5)
mainView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
mainView.clipsToBounds = false
mainView.layer.masksToBounds = false        
mainView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

Comment: Where are you adding this code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133109/fastest-way-to-do-shadows-on-ios/10133182#10133182

Comment: This code is added when a new cell is created.

Comment: Hi
You have to use UIBezierPath.